# Heroku: How do I add the YAML module to my PHP application?

Tags: php, heroku

I have a web app called PocketMine Tools and I have it running on my VPS server. When I deployed it to Heroku I got a error when parsing a YAML file. This is why I need php-yaml but i was unable to find a way. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

https://github.com/pmt-mcpe-fun/WebApp/tree/heroku

This is probably a stupid question but I would like some help.

Heroku: heroku.mcpe.fun
VPS: pmt.mcpe.fun

Comment: You need to add composer.json with the yaml bundle required within, then heroku will run composer install.

Comment: Sorry but I am a total noob. Could you give that in a little bit more detail?

Comment: Like you have done now within your composer however I'd personally have used symfony/yaml is it still not functioning?

Comment: I've just had a proper look at your code. What is your actual error, are you sure the file you are trying to parse is Infact valid yaml?

Comment: What is the name of the package?